# How to fix missing SQL connection manager in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, oledb

I am trying to create an OLE DB connection in SSIS that I want to use for this package I am building which basically is supposed to do an ETL having it's source from Excel and the output in a SQL table. However, I am getting the error as below when trying to connect to the server and check in. I am using windows authentication and trying to connect locally using the '.' I also couldn't find the sql server configuration manager in my computer. I reinstalled my management studio 2018 version, but the didn't fix it either. Any insights would help on resolving this issue.

Thanks

#### Error message:

> TITLE: Connection Manager
>
> ---
>
> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Login timeout expired A network-related or instance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see SQL Server Books Online. Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server.

Comment: Are you sure there is a SQL database engine installed or that the service is running. Since management studio is a separate product. You can check that from the windows services.

Comment: yes I do have management studio installed and have been working on it

Comment: SSMS is the client tool for SQL Server, it is not the database engine. Read @Hadi statement again and check your Windows Services for SQL Server services to see if they exist.

Comment: okay so it doesn't. That is my first concern. Sql server configuration manger should have shown up here, but it doesn't. And the thing is, I do have SSIS and SSMS installed and use them everyday

Comment: I mean it doesn't show up under the services and applications drop down in my computer management

Comment: @Mahee try to replace `.`  with fully qualified name `<machine name>\<instance name>`

Comment: Are you doing your development on the SQL Server box directly? Connecting to `.` or `localhost` only works if you are initiating the connection from the server itself. Judging by the error, SSIS can't find a server to connect to at `.`. Have you tried specifying the SQL Server instance name instead?

Comment: SQL Server Configuration Manager isn't part of an SSMS installation. If you want to use SSCM to enable/disable client protocols, manage server aliases, etc., then you'll need to run the setup.exe from an SQL Server .iso/DVD and install the "Client Tools."

Comment: Far as I know, if you have more than one SQL Server instances installed on the machine that you trying to configure the connection manager, using `.` won't work.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the valuable insights. It looks like I was connected to the right server and got the new server name and everything worked just fine.